# Reliability or Robustness Testing a Web Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, testing, architecture

I have just built a proof of concept for an asp.net MVC controller to (1) generate a barcode from user input using barcode rendering framework and (2) embed it in a PDF document using wkhtmltopdf.exe

Before telling my client it's a working solution, I want to know it's not going to bring down their website. My main concern is long-term reliability -- whether for instance creating and disposing the unmanaged system process for wkhtmltopdf.exe might leak something. (Peak performance and load is *not* expected to be such an issue - only a few requests per minute at peak).

So, I run a couple of tests from the Windows command line:

(1) 1,000 Requests in Sequence (ie 1 at a time)

```
for /l %i in (1,1,1000) do curl ^
"http://localhost:8003/Home/Test?text=Iteration_%i___012345&scale=2&height=50" -o output.pdf
```

(2) Up to 40 requests sent within 2 seconds

```
for /l %i in (1,1,40) do start "Curl %i" curl ^
"http://localhost:8003/Home/Test?text=Iteration_%i___012345&scale=2&height=50" -o output%i.pdf
```

And I record some performance counters in perfmon before, during & after. Specifically I look at total processes, threads, handles, memory, disk use on the machine and on the IIS process specifically.

So, my questions:

1) What would you consider acceptable evidence that the the solution looks to be at low risk of bringing down the server? Would you amend what I've done, or would you do something completely different?

2) Given my concern is reliability, I think that the 'Before' vs 'After' figures are the ones I most care about. Agree or not?

3) Looking at the Before vs After figures, the only concern I see is the 'Processes Total Handle Count'. I conclude that launching wkhtmltopdf.exe nearly a thousand times has probably not leaked anything or destabilised the machine. But I might be wrong and should run the same tests for hours or days to reduce the level of doubt. Agree or not?

(The risk level: A couple of people's jobs might be on the line if it went pear-shaped. Revenue on the site is £1,000s per hour).

My perfmon results were as follows.

700 Requests in Sequence

```
                                1-5 Mins                                 10 Mins
Counter                      Before Test        Min     Ave     Max   After Test
System
System Processes                       95         97     100     101           95
System Threads                       1220       1245    1264    1281         1238
Memory Available MB                  4888       4840    4850    4868         4837
Memory % Committed                     23         24      24      24           24
Processes Total Handle Cou          33255      34147   34489   34775        34029
Processor % Processor Time       4 to 30          40      57      78     1 to 30
Physical Disk % Disk Time               1          0       7      75     0 to 30
IIS Express
% Processor Time                        0          0       2       6            0
Handle Count                          610        595     640     690          614
Thread Count                           34         35      35      35           35
Working Set                           138        139     139     139          139
IO Data KB/sec                          0        453     491     691            0
```

20 Requests sent within 2 seconds followed by 40 Requests sent within 3 seconds

```
                                1-5 Mins                                10 Mins
Counter                      Before Test        Min     Ave     Max     After Test
System
System Processes                       95         98     137     257           96
System Threads                       1238       1251    1425    1913         1240
Memory Available MB                  4837       4309    4694    4818         4811
Memory % Committed                     24         24      25      29           24
Processes Total Handle Cou          34029      34953   38539   52140        34800
Processor % Processor Time       1 to 30           1      48     100     1 to 10
Physical Disk % Disk Time        0 to 30           0       7     136     0 to 10
IIS Express
% Processor Time                        0          0       1      29            0
Handle Count                          610        664     818     936          834
Thread Count                           34         37      50      68           37
Working Set                           138        139     142     157          141
IO Data KB/sec                          0          0     186    2559            0
```

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't believe it fits StackOverflow; you're after a fair number of opinions here (and there's no guarantee that the opinions you would get would necessarily be valid, either). Another StackExchange site may be more suitable.

Comment: I'm looking for 'No, you've made fundamental mistake X in your approach'. Or affirmation that I haven't. I think my question is very specific for a q about software architecture & quality attribute testing

Comment: The issue is that you've given your opinions, and then asked whether others agree or disagree; agreeing or disagreeing with an opinion is in itself an opinion, and thus this falls within "primarily opinion-based". You might find that this is a better fit within ServerFault.com.